# Python parse log using regex

Tags: python, json, regex, syslog

Hope someone might be able to help. I have a log been sent from a syslog server to python which looks like this:

```
{'Raw': 'Nov 26 00:23:07 TEST 23856434232342 (2016-11-26T00:23:07) http-proxy[2063]: Allow 1-Trusted 0-External tcp 192.168.0.1 2.3.4.5 57405 80 msg="HTTP Request" proxy_act="HTTP-TEST" op="POST" dstname="www.google.com" arg="/" sent_bytes="351" rcvd_bytes="1400"  (HTTP-proxy-TEST-00)'}
```

I need to be able to extract the IP address, `dstname=`, `sent_bytes=` and `dcvd_bytes=` and if possible parse to json. I started trying to use `REGEX (["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`  to match the double quotes but its not working correctly.

Any ideas how I might get the data I need? Or how to parse the above to json?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming IP, dstname sent_bytes and rcvd_bytes are always in order, use `re.findall` to get them all

```
import re
s = r"""{'Raw': 'Nov 26 00:23:07 TEST 23856434232342 (2016-11-26T00:23:07) http-proxy[2063]: Allow 1-Trusted 0-External tcp 192.168.0.1 2.3.4.5 57405 80 msg="HTTP Request" proxy_act="HTTP-TEST" op="POST" dstname="www.google.com" arg="/" sent_bytes="351" rcvd_bytes="1400" (HTTP-proxy-TEST-00)'}"""

match = re.findall('(?:tcp |dstname=|sent_bytes=|rcvd_bytes=)"?([^\s"]+)', s)
# match = ['192.168.0.1', 'www.google.com', '351', '1400']
(ip, dstname, sent_bytes, rcvd_bytes) = match
# use this to parse to json
```